# How to animate an icon for with CSS?

Tags: css, css-animations

Is it possible, using CSS, to show a lock icon (in *locked* state) and then on hover, have it animated to *unlocked* state (as seen below)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely possible, you can try SVG sprite-sheets incorporated with CSS keyframes;

Create an SVG file for all frames of the animation, and have it as the background for the desired element (an anchor element in our case, let's anotate it with the `svg` classname):

```css
a.svg {
    background-image: url(lock.svg);
}
```

You'd also have to account for the aspect ratio of the SVG image, so set it as well, e.g.:

```css
a.svg {
    width: 1200%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Now you have to wrap that in a clipping container to hide all that extra width, so put it inside another element, grunt it with absolute dimensions and set its `overflow` property to `hidden`, say, like so:

```html
<div class="clip">
    <a class="svg" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

```css
.clip {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Now we'd want to declare the keyframes transformations to be used, we're just moving along the X axis here, so:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes lock {
    from { -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); }
    to { -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0); }
}
```

And using it in steps according to the number of frames we have in our SVG sprite-sheet:

```css
a.svg {
    -webkit-animation: lock 1s steps(12, end);
}
```

Wait! let's take a step back here (no pun intended), as we need the animation to be activated *on hover*. We do that with CSS transitions on the `:hover` state. Well, erase that last rule and do the following instead:

```css
a.svg {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-animation;
}
a.svg:hover {
    -webkit-animation: lock 1s steps(12, end);
}
```

#### Notes

- This is all shamelessly borrowed from [Veljko Sekelj's magnificent post](https://plus.google.com/100663135211813370970/posts/Tmd6tL28ZFD), introducing this technique.
- Properties are all Webkit oriented, due testing with Webkit driven browsers. This could probably be achieved in Gecko as well.
- This will work with any container size, as we're dealing with vector graphics, and our background carrier is flexed-layout and will fit the dimensions of its container.
- There is still some work to be done, as we also need to toggle states between *locked* and *unlocked*, this is not covered here (yet). I'm thinking we could run the animation in reverse.

---

*I will update this post real soon to include a live working demo, but this should give you a head start on what you're looking for. Go ahead and read Veljko Sekelj's post, play with the code, twist it, turn it, go berzerk, man.*

Comment: An animated GIF is a much more practical approach in most cases but an SVG does have the advantage of not being a raster graphic, i.e. it will scale flawlessly on high density displays (which are becoming more and more common). So +1 from me.

Comment: thanks, i believe that was the initial intent for Veljko's experiments - seamless rendering across displays.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can. I tried by leveraging the CSS3 rotation coupled with transform-origin. In my example below I just set the following values on the part we want to animate on hover.

```
transform: rotateY(-180deg);
transform-origin: 25px 0;
```

This is just an example (far from perfect, but definitely working). 
You can use two images if you prefer using the same logic, or even try to make it with only CSS as I did but maybe in one element only.

Here's my [working demo](http://codepen.io/nobitagit/pen/xCmap) (webkit only, but works in all major browsers with appropriate prefixes).

Answer (score 0):

witch css animation, you can't, but see my trick :

with `:hover` you can change background-image
for example :

```
a {
    background: url(lock.png) no-repeat center center;
}
a:hover {
    background-image: url(unlock.gif);
}
```

unlock.gif is animate gif file start from lock to unlock image animate

Comment: I had added a similar answer (css sprites), but I really think the OP is wanting to animate it, not just flip images. (I deleted my answer).

Comment: @Graeck i say hover image must be animated gif

Comment: nice, simple solution, s*** i really went nuts for this (see my answer) **:)**